# I cant seem to figure out folder structure and it says the system cant find my file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, aurelia

can't seem to figure out what the problem with my file structure might be. I'm using Aurelia as a front end and node for the server. I did a join that fixed some of the issues but now I'm getting this error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/src/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/main.js
```

This is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    engines = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    assert = require('assert'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ useNewUrlParser: true }));


    app.use('/scripts', express.static(require('path').join(__dirname, 'scripts')));

    function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.stack);
        res.status(500).render('error_template', {err: err});
    }

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', function(err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log('MongoDB connected!')

        var db = client.db('todos');

        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.render('index', {});
        });

        app.use(errorHandler);
    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
        var port = server.address().port;
        console.log("Express server listening on port %s.", port);
    });
```

[image: This is my folder structure:]

Comment: Your code shows `app.use('/scripts', ...)` but your requests are not going to `/scripts...`, they're going to `/src...`.

Comment: This is an issue (to be solved) with express. Your local files should be served remotely, but you're missing that setting  `app.use(express.static('src'))`

Comment: @KirkLarkin How would I solve this issue?

Comment: @Daniel so should I just do app.use(express.static('src))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(require('path').join(__dirname, 'scripts')));
```

This line of code takes a local folder and makes it available through the express server. You need to do the same thing for your `src` folder

either with:

```
app.use('/src', express.static(require('path').join(__dirname, 'src')));
```

or:

```
app.use(express.static(require('path').join(__dirname, 'src')));
```

the first parameter allows you to name the directory it will be served as, which is usually the same.

And even though I didn't include the `require('path').join(__dirname,...` in the comment, it's good practice to include it.